# Ordering functions by Big O complexity

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to order the following functions in terms of Big O complexity from low complexity to high complexity: `4^(log(N))`,  `2N`, `3^100`, `log(log(N))`, `5N`, `N!`,  `(log(N))^2`

This:

1. `3^100`
2. `log(log(N))`
3. `2N`
4. `5N`
5. `(log(N))^2`
6. `4^(log(N))`
7. `N!`

I figured this out just by using the chart given on wikipedia. Is there a way of verifying the answer?

Comment: This sort of question probably works better on cstheory.stackexchange.com, as it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
3^100 = O(1)
log log N = O(log log N)
(log N)^2 = O((log N)^2)
N, 2N, 5N = O(N)
4^logN = O(e^logN)
N! = o(N!)
```

you made just one small mistake. this is the right order.